# Calculating odds of a dependent series

Tags: probability

I ran into an interesting probability question today, and I can't tell which of two ways to solve it is valid.

Initially, there are two targets: $H$ and $M$.  A target is picked three times, but $M$ can only be picked twice. What are the odds that $M$ is picked twice?

---

**Solution 1**

- There are 7 possible outcomes: $\{HHH, HHM, HMH, HMM, MHH, MHM, MMH\}$
- Three of these have the desired result: $\{HMM, MHM, MMH\}$
- Therefore, there is $3/7 \approx 43\%$ chance of $M$ being picked twice.

**Solution 2**

- There are 2 possible first picks, 50% likely each: $\{H, M\}$
- There are 4 possible followups, 25% likely each: $\{HH, HM, MH, MM\}$
- One of these is our goal state, and there are 6 possible followups from the others, each with 12.5% likelihood: $\{HHH, HHM, HMH, HMM, MHH, MHM\}$
- There are two 12.5% options and one 25% option, resulting in 50% chance of $M$ being picked twice.

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment: Solution 2 should be the correct one. Since not all of the 7 outcomes listed in solution 1 have equal likelyhood.

Comment: @user130512 - Why don't they?  Does MMH count double because MMM isn't valid?  That would seem to be the reasoning from #2, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Let us assign probabilities to each of the events in solution 1. For six of them, the probability is $\frac18$, but for MMH, the probability is $\frac14$ (since MM has a P(1/4), and the last H has P(1)). Thus, you can't say the answer is 3/7 and must use solution 2

Comment: I see, I think.  All the other threes have P(1/4)*P(1/2), but MM flows to a P(1/4)*P(0) and a P(1/4)*P(1) instead.  Right?

Comment: Right, that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 2 is correct because you must take into account the individual probabilities of each combination of H and M happening.

As you have said in solution 2, the probability of MMH is not $\frac18$ like the others, but $\frac14$ because the probability of MMM is 0, and the probability of MMH given MM is 1.

Thus, adding the probabilites of MHM, HMM and MMH gives you $\frac18 + \frac18 + \frac14 = \frac12$

Solution 1 would be correct only if all of the events listed in the sample space have equal probabilities of occuring, ($\frac17$ in this case).